# Train_test_split produces unexpected sample size due to rounding

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm building a logistic regression-based machine learning problem using `sklearn`. I'm essentially trying to simulate running the model each day to make a decision for the following day.

To get `train_test_split` to take the set of choices available on the "test" day, I just set the split to:

`splt = 1/observ_days`

The size of the observation set is the observed days * available choices, which changes slightly depending on availability, but in the problem case is 45. So the total observations = 45 * observ_days, and the test set should be 45.

The challenges is that train_test_split always rounds up, so when you get a common floating number issue, it could produce an unexpected split. Specifically in my case when the observed days is 744. 1/744 = 0.0013440860215053765. The size of the total data at that moment is 33480. In normal math, 33480 * the split = 45, like it should. But Python comes up with 45.00000000000001, so `train_test_split` gives me 46 test observations.

That's a problem because in my case the 46th observation is actually from another day. Is there a way to force `train_test_split` to round down? Or impute the exact size of the train/test set manually?

Comment: Is there a reason for not just specifying test_size = 45? Check the documentation, you can pass float(proportion of the whole dataset) or int(number of datapoints to take into test_size). Also note that train_test_split makes a random split, so even with 45 values only in test_set it's likely most values will not be from the same day.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it. FWIW, if you set `shuffle` to `False` the test set will be the last of `test_size`, so your solution solves all my problems.

Comment: No worries. And thanks for the 'shuffle' bit, wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [scikit-learn documentation for train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) you'll notice you can specify *train_size* or *test_size* as both **float** (as a proportion of whole dataset to be used) and **int** (as a specific number of datapoints to be included).

In your case you could just specify `test_size = 45` to always take exactly 45 datapoints for the test_set.